# Is there a safe way to get the first not-undefined variable from a set of variables?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm trying to get the first occurrence of a non-undefined value from a set of variables. Like so:

```
// var1 and var3 are undefined
with(p = var1 || var2 || var3){
    // Do something
}
```

But the console throws a `var1 is not defined` error if it finds an undefined variable before a defined variable.

Is there a way to do this shorthand, or do I have to check individually for every variable?

Comment: do you mean undeclared?

Comment: 1) Don't use `with`. 2) If you need to check whether a variable has been declared or not, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Don't use [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), and don't reference undeclared variables. Neither of these are good practices.

Comment: `typeof x === 'undefined'` is the only way to check *undeclared* variables. This is specific to the `typeof`operator (because it doesn't try to resolve the variable). But if you have to check whether a variable is declared or not, then you probably have other problems. Can you explain why you need this?

Comment: ... or if it is a global variable `window.var1` wouldn't throw

Comment: @JonasWilms: Wouldn't work for `const`, `let` or `class` though because they don't create properties on the global object.